# Deploy Laravel application to multiple environments from multiple branches - bitbucket pipelines

Tags: laravel, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

I am trying to define multiple environment builds in Bitbucket pipelines based on the push trigger in a specific branch. But I am getting an error:

```
There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > branches > master > 0]. To be precise: Step is empty, null, or missing.
```

I have defined variable $DEPLOY_PATH in each environments. $host and $user are defined as global variables.

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: Production
        script:
          - cd $DEPLOY_PATH; cat ./deploy.sh | ssh $user@$host
          - echo "Deploy step finished"
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: Production
    dev-master:
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: Development
    test-master:
      - step:
        <<: *Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: Test
```

My deploy.sh:

```
echo "Deploy script started"
sh pull.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself.
bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: atlassian/default-image:latest

definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &Deploy-step
        name: Deploy to production
        deployment: Production
        script:
          - eval ssh -T $user@$host \"$(cat ./deploy.sh | tr '\n' ';')\"
          - echo "Deploy step finished"
          
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step: *Deploy-step
    dev-master:
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          name: Deploy to development
          deployment: Development
    test-master:
      - step:
          <<: *Deploy-step
          name: Deploy to test
          deployment: Test
```

deploy.sh file:

```
echo "Deploy script started"
cd $DEPLOY_PATH
sh pull.sh
echo "Deploy script finished execution"
```

pull.sh file which is in the $DEPLOY_PATH directory on server:

```
php artisan down
git pull origin master
composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan up
echo 'Deploy finished.'
```

*The error was due to missing indentation below `step:` -> before `<<*` and below two other lines